# Java: how to get ssl session data from ssl certificate?

Tags: java, ssl-certificate

I have an SSL Certificate that is represented by `sun.security.x509.X509CertInfo`. It contains different data on Organization, Organization Unit, Domain name and so on. But I need to get Protocol and Cipher data.

`SSLSession` interface has methods to retrieve this data `getProtocol()` and `getCipherSuite()`. Is it possible to retrieve this data (Protocol and Cipher) having only SSL Certificate object?

Comment: The cipher suite and protocol are associated with the session, not the certificate. Any given certificate could be associated over time with any number of combinations of cipher suite and protocol. The question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, simply because a certificate does not contain that information. It's setup  during the protocol negotiation part of SSL, and is mostly independent of the certificate properties.

Comment: Unfortunately. I had to return back to the moment of SSL Session initialization to save this data and pass further with the cert.